# I want to combine these 4 stored procedures to one since all of them return same data (almost)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Below are my stored procedures. I want to combine all of these into a single stored procedure to reduce redundancy. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Stored procedure 1:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_FetchSkillBlockToAddPR]
AS
SELECT
  sb.skillblockid
 ,sb.skillblockcd
FROM
  skillblock AS sb
 ,skillfamily
 ,lineofbusiness AS lb
WHERE
  skillfamily.skillfamilyid = sb.skillfamilyid
  AND lb.lineofbusinessid = skillfamily.lineofbusinessid
  AND lb.lineofbusinesscode IN
        ( 'PL' )
  AND sb.activeflag = 'Y'
ORDER BY
  sb.skillblockcd;
```

Stored procedure 2:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_FetchSkillBlockToUpdateTeamData]
AS
SELECT
  SkillBlock.SkillBlockId
 ,SkillBlock.SkillBlockCd
 ,SkillBlock.SkillBlockName
FROM
  SkillBlock
  INNER JOIN
    SkillFamily
      ON
      SkillFamily.SkillFamilyId = SkillBlock.SkillFamilyId
WHERE
  SkillFamily.LineOfBusinessId = 27
  AND SkillBlock.ActiveFlag = 'Y'
  AND SkillFamily.ActiveFlag = 'Y';
```

Stored procedure 3:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_FetchSkillBlockBySkillBlockCd]
AS
SELECT
  skillblockid
 ,SkillblockCd
FROM
  skillblock
 ,skillfamily
WHERE
  skillblock.skillfamilyid = skillfamily.skillfamilyid
  AND lineofbusinessid = 27
ORDER BY
  Skillblockcd;
```

Stored procedure 4:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_FetchSkillBlock]
AS
SELECT
  sb.skillblockid
 ,sb.skillblockcd
FROM
  skillblock AS sb
 ,skillfamily AS sf
 ,lineofbusiness AS lb
WHERE
  sf.skillfamilyid = sb.skillfamilyid
  AND lb.lineofbusinessid = sf.lineofbusinessid
  AND lb.lineofbusinesscode IN ( 'PL' );
```

Comment: Please don't code dump, tell the SO volunteer community to review your code, and expect a solution. What is different about them, what leg work have you done, and what specific issue can we help with?

Comment: What calls these stored procedures? Why don't you use parameters in 1 stored proc to return what you need?

Comment: Something that you can do is create a SP encapsulates all three statements and have an input param that accepts a string which you can pass during the calling. i.e AddPR if you want to run the first query and so on..

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s agreed. No prefix needed. A verb (the action) in the name can indicate a procedure, i.e. Sales.Invoice_Create, Sales.Invoice_Update, etc.

Comment: Solved it. Thanks for your help everyone. Will keep that in mind @marc_s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start using explicit joins. [Here's a good blog on that.](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

With that being said, your requirements are very broad. But the simplest way to combine those which pull from different tables and return different columns with different predicates it is:

```
create myLargerProc(@choice int)
as

if @choice = 1
begin
--code from first proc
end

if @choice = 2
begin
--code from second proc
end

--etc....
```

You could make the parameter a varchar and take user input or whatever you want.

Comment: Solved it. See above. Thanks for your suggestion @scsimon

Comment: Proc 2 returns 3 columns... but your solution doesn’t

Comment: Yeah. Sorry. I didn't see that. I don't need the 3rd column actually. @scsimon

Comment: Well also some of your procedures only query two tables where other one worry three with an inner join which would change the results. So the solution couldn’t bring back the same results as the individual price, or could t be guaranteed to at least

Comment: Yeah. You are right @scsimon. But, I've changed the Stored Procedure as required and I'm getting the results I needed. Thanks!

Comment: No problem  @LegendKiller but be ware it will bring back different results eventually

Comment: Sure. I'll see what I can do. Thanks @scsimon

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:** Combined all the above Stored Procedures into a single one like this so that the same thing can be called from multiple blocks of code.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_FetchSkillBlock]

@p_ActiveFlagSB char(1) = NULL,
@p_ActiveFlagSF char(1) = NULL

AS

select sb.skillblockid, sb.skillblockcd 
from skillblock as sb, skillfamily as sf, lineofbusiness as lb 
where sf.skillfamilyid=sb.skillfamilyid AND         
lb.lineofbusinessid=sf.lineofbusinessid AND lb.lineofbusinesscode in ('PL') 
AND ((@p_ActiveFlagSB IS NULL) OR (sb.ActiveFlag = @p_ActiveFlagSB))
AND ((@p_ActiveFlagSF IS NULL) OR (sf.ActiveFlag = @p_ActiveFlagSF))
order by sb.SkillBlockCd
```

Comment: https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/